# 403 forbidden error mobilefirst platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rest-client, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I created a MobileFirst Adapter with security enabled. I generated token and when I try to call the API, I get 403 Forbidden error. The same works well when on localhost but gives this error when deployed on Server. I have attached the screenshot from REST Client below.

I'm using MFP 7.0.0 version

[403 Error from REST Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98OUg.png)

Log file:

[11/2/15 5:24:57:786 CST] 000049b7 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.ApplicationErrorUtils           E SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest:195'
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:195)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox$2.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:377)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:84)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:382)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.RESTAdaptersServiceServlet.doService(RESTAdaptersServiceServlet.java:69)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.RESTAdaptersServlet.service(RESTAdaptersServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:863)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:253)

Comment: Do you have any code for us?

Comment: Did you define the scope realms in application-descriptor.xml?

Comment: @Idan Yes, I have defined the scope realms in authenticationConfig.xml I'm using MFP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated this issue intensively , as our needs was to call new java adapter (JAX-RS implementation ) that is protected with @OuathSecurity via REST Clients.

But i will need to ask you few questions to give you better answer:

- Is this the scenario you need ?
- Did you generate token using this documentation 
  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_non_mobile_to_mobile_services.html?lang=en

**Or** you are using the test token end point ?

Comment: Yes, I want to call a java adapter via rest client. The API is protected with `@OAuthSecurity(scope="default")` and I defined the Realm "default" in authenticationConfig.xml under server/conf in MFP Project(in eclipse). I generated the test token using authentication/v1/testtoken url from localhost. I'm using MFP 7.0.0 version. I get the API response after adding the token in header and running in REST client while connecting to localhost. But the same doesn't work after deploying on dedicated server.

Comment: The short answer that unfortunately this will not work , the adapters (with security enabled) is built to receive token that consist of two parts                       1)Access Token                                                                                                                 2)ID token( digital signature of device info such as model , platform , device id )   which you will not be able to get as you will be calling from a non mobile context

Comment: -The analytic service uses this info to log the adapter calls with this device info (extracted from ID token )                                                                                         -Also the test token exist only in the development environment , it's ID token contains information about dummy device

Comment: we followed this link  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_non_mobile_to_mobile_services.html?lang=en                         to generate a valid access token to use it with REST client calls , it succeeded and passed security , but it did not contain the ID token (device info ) so it throw error code 500 (internal server error ) related to analytic service trying to log null device info                                                                           i did not find any way yet to generate the ID token , as it generated by client

Comment: you can try to  use the link i mentioned to generate a valid access token , and use the ID token from test token (test token contains access token + id token separated by a space) , but i am not sure it will work , as the test token according to documentation is for development environment only.

Comment: - the adapter with security disabled , can be called by REST clients,                   so in theory , you can develop your own Ouath Security authentication and use it instead of mobile first authentication

Comment: I am able to view the response by adding the developer env. token. 

When it is deployed on server, the frontend code generates the token from MFP and is able to view responses of other adapter's APIs. But 1 adapter is failing with the above image error and error logs. 

That is strange. With same security code and API code, other adapters are working fine but this 1 adapter is failing with 403 forbidden error and logs shows ParseException. Can you please see if you can get anything from logs. Thanks

Comment: for some reason parse exception occurred  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest , casuing it to throw javax.servlet.ServletException which the server did not find it's class definition , does this adapter always fail ? if you disable this adapter security does it work ?